# How to draw Custom UIView in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

How can I draw custom view  as shown in image.
I want to draw a small rectangle in main view.

plaese refer any link if you have.

## Image

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It could be as simple as below

```
import UIKit

class Rectangle:UIView{

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:rect.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width/2,y:rect.height/1.4))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:rect.width,y:rect.height))
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

}

let rect=Rectangle(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Comment: Thank you but can you please give me in Objective c?

Comment: This solution is incomplete and doesn't actually draw anything other than create a `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: @Camsoft - It does render https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/154541/174355501-c602eb27-69b2-44ec-8f4c-9851e843b281.png